# How to test content inside a pod in openshift?

Tags: testing, kubernetes, automated-tests, rubygems, openshift

I am writing an automated test that will run everytime a cluster is created. As part of this test, I need to read the content of a file inside a pod and verify a specific string exists or not. How can I achieve this?

Currently we are using Gem Train Kubernetes. It is capable of verifying that the pod exists or not. However, how can I verify the content inside a file in this pod?

If there is another tool or test suite that I can use, I don't mind using that. I just need some pointers. Is this possible via inspec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the mechanisms provided by `kubectl` are going to be the least amount of drama, but I have no idea what Gem Train Kubernetes is in order to speak to that specifically

You can grep for the content in the Pod, if it has a shell and grep available:

```
kubectl exec $the_pod_name -- sh -c 'grep TheStringYouWant /the/path/you/are/testing'
```

or you can copy the file off of the Pod if you need to do something more complex and the file isn't too big:

```
kubectl cp ${the_pod_name}:/the/path/in/the/pod ./to/local
```

Comment: Thank you mdaniel. I think this can only be automated by creating a bash script or python script. Isn't it?